# Java Segment Big array Data

Tags: java

I have a huge data in the below format

```
      TIME STAMP    Sum of T2I Obj
      11/17/2014 00:02:13 a 0.524
      11/17/2014 00:05:49 a 2.104
      11/17/2014 00:09:06 a 3.245
      11/17/2014 00:14:25 a 13.427
      11/17/2014 00:15:36 a 2.832
      11/17/2014 00:17:13 a 3.098
      11/17/2014 00:20:49 a 0.751
      11/17/2014 00:24:16 a 0.884
```

Full Input:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/168ejowAajGfXv-JBQKm7u3_G8-oPM8Mfn1TC-3MzXsA/edit?usp=sharing

Processed File Output: (see Last sheet one hour output and need to change that to eight hour)

MY FULL CODE Tried:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzTX2wIhk3Wza1lGVmhHcFZQX0k/view?usp=sharing

As you can see the above file has date time in one column and values in other column.

I want to segment all the single data to combined data for 8hr interval.

ie

```
  TIME STAMP      Average
  11/17/2014 08    0.524 (AVG of all the data between 00hr -8hr)
  11/17/2014 16    2.104 (AVG of all the data between 08hr -16hr)
  11/17/2014 24    3.245 (AVG of all the data between 16hr -24hr)
```

Any help from the Java experts!!

Comment: First things first: I don't see an actual question here and since no one will just write some code out of the blue, you might want to tell us with what exactly you are struggling with. Then a question: how exactly will your result be calculated? (e.g. why the intervals 0h-8h, 8h-16h etc.. where do they come from?)

Comment: HI @ Dinistro I atttched the full code and the input file. I am able to process the output for each hour. I am finding some challenge for combining 8hrs.

Comment: Output file is attached below.. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWbVD0HF349KNCTxR2UJzpXuKCNSq0eHPU4Uf9qdZHQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do here is a ETL process. Its better to use some framework which does that like [kettle](http://etl-tools.info/en/pentaho/kettle-etl.htm) for example. If you are having a distributed data then better using [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) mapreduce jobs would help.

Comment: In one of my previous projects team had used kettle with drule to solve the ETL pattern needed. I have not used it personally though.